# Is this Corollary a historical or modern product?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, math-history, cayley-hamilton

I saw this Corollary on page 21 of [this book](https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Eplotkin/resources/MFAtiyah_IGMacDonald_IntroToCommAlgebra.pdf) *"Introduction to commutative algebra"* by Atiyah and Macdonald.

> Corollary 2.5. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module and let $a$ be an ideal of $A$ such that $aM=M$. Then there exists $x \equiv 1 \pmod {a}$ such that $xM=0$

However, I think this acts like a stepping stone from the generalized version of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to the Nakayama lemma.  But I'm curious how this Corollary came about.  Did this corollary appear in a historical development process, or is it a corollary that was put in to make it easier to understand from a modern perspective?

Comment: Allow me to quip that it's not a "stepping stone" from CH to the Nakayama lemma, but _is_ simply (a version of) the Nakayama lemma. In fact, Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory" takes this formulation as its version of the famous result. If you squint a bit and it looks reasonably like the Nakayama lemma, then it's probably the Nakayama lemma to somebody...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jacobson's 1945 paper, "[The Radical and Semi-Simplicity for Arbitrary Rings](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371731?origin=crossref)", has

> Theorem 10. If $\mathfrak{N}$ is a right ideal with a finite basis contained in the radical $\mathfrak{R}$ then either $\mathfrak{N}\mathfrak{R} < \mathfrak{N}$ or $\mathfrak{N} =0$

Azumaya's 1951 "[On Maximally Central Algebras](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/article/on-maximally-central-algebras/3EA03ADC0AF12EF65D5F75F485C10E89)" goes

> Following N. Jacobson$^{7)}$ the *radical* $N$ of $R$ is defined to be the join of all quasi-regular right ideals of $R$. [...]
>
> Theorem 1. Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be a finitely generated $R$-right-module such that $\mathfrak{M}N = \mathfrak{M}$. Then necessarily $\mathfrak{M} = 0$
>
> The proof is virtually the same as that of Jacobson [9], Theorem 10, [...]
>
> From now on, we assume that $K$ is a commutative ring with unit element
> and when we deal with moduli with operator ring $K$ we assume always that the
> unit element of $K$ operates as an identity endomorphism.
>
> Theorem 5. Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be a finite $K$-module such that $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{M}=\mathfrak{M}$ for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$. Then we have $\mathfrak{M} = 0$

and Nakayama's 1951 "[A Remark on Finitely Generated Modules](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/article/remark-on-finitely-generated-modules/8ECAE429F97A64E8F598A39B7E4EA48E)" follows

> Theorem 5 of Azumaya's recent article$^{1)}$ can be formulated in the following generalized form:
>
> **I.** Let $R$ be a ring. Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a finitely generated right-module of $R$ such that $\mathfrak{m}R = \mathfrak{m}$. Assume that $\mathfrak{m} = u_1r+u_2r+...+u_mr$ for every generating system $u_1+u_2+...+u_m$ of $\mathfrak{m}$ and for every maximal right-ideal $r$ of $R$. Then $\mathfrak{m} = 0$ [...]
>
> It is perhaps of interest to observe that from this generalization Jacobson's theorem$^{2)}$ may be derived:
>
> **II.** Let $R$ be a ring and $N$ be its radical. If $\mathfrak{m}$ is a finitely generated right-module of $R$ and if $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}N$, then $\mathfrak{m} = 0$ [...]
>
> **III.** In I we may restrict ourselves to those maximal right-ideals $r$ which contain the radical $N$ [...]
>
> **IV.** If $M$ is a two-sided ideal and if $\mathfrak{m} = 0$ is the only finitely generated module with $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}M$, then $M \subseteq N$

then, Jacobson's "Lectures in abstract algebra" have no reference for either 'Krull' (besides the Krull-Schmidt theorem), 'Azumaya', or 'Nakayama', and only treat Cayley-Hamilton for matrices; no 'Nakayama' in Zariski-Samuel too

the form you quote appears in Bourbaki's "Commutative algebra", as 'Corollary 3.' in II.2.2; they use

> THEOREM 2 ("Nakayama's lemma"). - Let $M$ be an $A$-module and $\mathfrak{a}$ a two-sided ideal of $A$. Suppose that one of the following conditions is satisfied:
>
> (i) The $A$-module $M$ is finitely generated, and $\mathfrak{a}$ is contained in the radical of $A$.
>
> (ii) The ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is nilpontent.
>
> If $N$ is a submodule of $M$ such that $M = N + \mathfrak{a}M$, then we have  $N = M$. In particular, if the module $M$ is nonzero, then we have $M \neq \mathfrak{a}M$

from their "Algebra", VIII.9.3 as the last step in the proof; the generalized Cayley-Hamilton is "Proposition 20" also on "Algebra", III.8.11, relatively isolated; fact, they appear to occur isolated from one another generally

the same form you quote also appears on Matsumura's 1986 "Commutative Ring Theory" as 'Theorem 2.2', *this time* after the generalized Cayley-Hamilton;

the main point, I believe, linking this form to the earlier ones involving radicals is precisely the lemma Bourbaki uses to prove 'Corollary 3':

> LEMMA 1. For every ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $A$, the set $S$ of elements $1+a$, where $a \in \mathfrak{a}$, is a multiplicative subset of $A$ and the set $\mathfrak{a}'$ of elements of $S^{-1}A$ of the form $a/s$, where $a \in \mathfrak{a}$ and $s \in S$, is an ideal contained in the Jacobson radical of $S^{-1}A$